# Erlang creating list by splitting a list of tuples

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I have a list of tuples and I want to create the a list of elements from a specific position in the tuple.

My tuple is {A, B} and I have several of these in a list and i want to create the list of all the B elements.

Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I build a list of elements extracted from a list of tuples in Erlang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626189/how-do-i-build-a-list-of-elements-extracted-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-erlang)

Answer (score 3):

You can use lists:map.

```
1> A = [{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}].
[{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}]
2> B = lists:map(fun ({_, V}) -> V end, A).
[2,4,6]
```

The function passed to the map will select the element required from the tuple and the result will be a list of all the elements in that particular position in the given list of tuples. The above code assumes that all tuples have same number of elements.

Comment: Cheers! Works beutifuly

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way is to just use a simple list comprehension:

```
[B || {_, B} <- L].
```

Comment: It would be handy to know, if your pick this solution: if list contains tuples with other then 2 elements, they will be silently skipped. e.g.: `[b1, b2] = [ B || {_, B} <- [{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3, c3}] ].` In some cases it is desirable in some not.

Answer (score 1):

```
> L = [{a1,b1}, {a2,b2}, {a3,b3}].
[{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3}]
> lists:foldr(fun({_, B}, Acc) -> [B | Acc] end, [], L).
[b1,b2,b3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick sample, not tested, but it should work.

```
split_tuples([{A | B} | T], Acc) ->
    NewAcc = [B | Acc],
    split_tuples(T, NewAcc);
split_tuples([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

Answer (score 0):

erlang's `element/2` function does just that: return the nth element from a tuple.

Put that in a map or fold function, with position as a parameter, and you're done.

---

**edit**: some untested code example:

```
get_them_all(ListOfTuples,Index) ->
    lists:map(fun(Tuple) -> element(Index,Tuple) end,ListOfTuples).
```