# How do I build a list of elements extracted from a list of tuples in Erlang?

Tags: list, erlang

I have a list with elements like: {First, Second}
Now I want to build a list containing each First element from the first list, how do I do that?

Does this work:

```
List = [L || {First, Second} = FirstList, L <- First].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
Results = [First || {First, _Second} <- List].
```

It creates a list of `First`, where `{First, _Second}` comes from `List`.

We're using matching to decompose the tuples. The underscore on `_Second` denotes that we're not using it (and suppresses the warning to that effect). You could use a plain `_`, but I often use the longer form to sort-of document what's going on.

The resulting list is made up of all of the `First` values.

You can play with this stuff in the Erlang shell. To answer the question you posed in your comment:

```
1> Players = [{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}].
[{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}]
2> OtherPlayers = [{P,Q} || {P,Q} <- Players, Q =/= 3].
[{a,1},{b,2}]
```

Here, we're setting up the original list (I used atoms for player names, simple integers instead of pids). Then we create a new list of `{P,Q}` tuples, such that `{P,Q}` comes from the original list, with a filter that `Q =/= 3`.

You can read more about list comprehensions (and filters) in the [Erlang documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html) or in [Learn you Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Great! Is this the right way to exclude a tuple containing "FromPid":     
    
    OtherPlayers = [{P, Pid} || {P, Pid} <- Players, Pid /= FromPid],

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[L || {L,R} <- FirstList].
```